# How do I prevent an SQL database from being locked when using UPDATE?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a program that uses a couple sql databases to store data. I have a class that manages the various sql functions, such as getting a value, an entire table or just updating a value. All of the processes work fine until I run a function that uses UPDATE. I execute an UPDATE command and try to commit the change and the database is always locked. Every function I have in my custom sql class has

```
cursor.close
database.close
```

So there shouldn't be any issue with the database connection still being open. Am I missing something in this syntax that is not connecting to the database correctly? I used the extra print statements in an attempt to find out where the problem is occurring, so those can be ignored.

```
import sqlite3 as db
import os
databaseName = "site"

class MassDb:
    def __init__(self,databaseName):
        super(MassDb, self).__init__()
        print("Current Directory: ",os.getcwd())
        self.databaseName = databaseName  

    def updateValue(self, location, metric, input_value):
        print("OPEN CONNECTION UPDATE - running updateValue: ",location, metric, input_value)
        if self.databaseName == "site": 
            try: 
                siteConn = db.connect("site_data.db")
                siteCursor = siteConn.cursor()
                siteCursor.execute("UPDATE sites SET " + metric + " = ? WHERE LOCATI    ON = ?", (input_value, location))
                siteConn.commit()
            except: 
                print("UPDATE FAILED")
            finally: 
                siteCursor.close
                siteConn.close

        elif self.databaseName == "comp": 
            try: 
                compConn = db.connect("comp_data.db")
                compCursor = compConn.cursor()
                compCursor.execute("UPDATE competitors SET " + metric + " = ? WHERE NAME = ?", (input_value, location))
                compConn.commit()
            except: 
                print("UPDATE FAILED")
            finally: 
                compCursor.close
                compConn.close
                print("CLOSED CONNECTION UPDATE - Update Connection Closed")
        else: 
            print("Update Error")

MassDb("site").updateValue("Location", "CURRENT_SCORE", "100")
```

Comment: `siteCursor.close` doesn't close the database, you just bind the function to a name. You need `()` to actually call the function... `siteCursor.close()`. You do call sqlite methods elsewhere in the code, I'm not sure why you would assume this was an attribute?

Comment: I'm fairly new to python and even newer to sql, so I don't catch every mistake in my syntax yet. Thanks for the reply. I made the change and the issue persists, so there must be some other reason why it's not closing the database correctly.

Comment: Fair play if you're new to both, you've avoided some really common traps in your code. I'm taking another look.

Comment: `("UPDATE sites SET " + metric + " = ? WHERE LOCATI    ON = ?"` why the massive amount of whitespace?

Comment: In any case, I'm going off-course here (though it's a legitimate issue) because I'm not sure your handling of this situation will stop the database being locked on failure. You could use `with` context manager to handle opening and closing the connection. SQLite isn't really made for concurrency so there's always a chance the DB will be locked during the write but it's usually faster than the timeout for other connections. You can also look into the  Write Ahead Log (WAL)

Comment: * usually faster than the timeout of other connections that want to write to the DB.

Comment: I was able to track down in another class, a reference to the database that wasn't closed properly. I wouldn't have know to investigate that without your help, thank you. It also seems that if you commit a change, I don't need to close the cursor or database connection, which I did not know,

Comment: I wanted to use with to handle the connection to the db but I did so many searches for help on the syntax and came up short, so I had to abandon that method. I have seen people refer to WAL before, but I am completely unfamiliar with that at the moment. As for the whitespace, that was more for readability for myself. As I get more proficient with Python and can trust my code more, I'll probably make some changes to how I write a lot of things.

Comment: I think there's just too much opinion around sqlite floating about and the documentation is kinda heavy. It's hard to understand exactly how it behaves properly until there's an issue. 1 writer, multiple readers. Not closing a connection isn't necessarily an issue unless it hasn't commited writes. Caveat: possibly I'm just piling on more misinformation but that's how I've experienced it.

Comment: Well again, your help guided me to not just one problem I had but two and hopefully I won't make the mistake again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roganjosh commented, my problem was that I wasn't properly closing the database. If

```
commit()
```

is used, there's no need to close the database. However,

```
cursor.close()
```

and

```
conn.close()
```

need to be written as such. Leaving off the parentheses would be as though an attribute is being referenced, rather than a method. In order to execute the close method, the () must be present. Seems obvious now, but I wasn't aware at the time. Hopefully this can help someone else if they too run across this.

Additionally, using a context manager works and eliminates the need to use `close()`

```
with conn:
    #do stuff here
    commit()
```

Comment: Using the context manager is a good fix. I had the same issue and this took the guess work out of 'did I close the connection?' or not.